# how create dynamic textfield and get value from each textfield in jetpack compose?

Tags: textfield, android-jetpack-compose

let say I have this composable function to create outlineTextField

```
val valueState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

myLists.forEach{ item -> 
             OutlinedTextField(
                value = valueState.value,
                onValueChange = {
                    valueState.value = it
                }
             )
    
    }

Button(
    onClick= { 
      valueState.value  // want to print each value from OutlinedTextField here..
    }
){
     Text("Click Me")
}
```

Amount of OutlinedTextField will be create based on looping.

**Question**

how to get value from each textField ?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want here or maybe the sample code is not enough. Here, you're sharing each text field input with the same value. I assume you want each text field to have its own value right?

Comment: yes, each textField have its own value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `mutableStateListOf`

```
val myLists = listOf("xx","xx","xxx")
val textFieldInitValues = List(myLists.size){ "" }
val valueStateList = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>().apply { addAll(textFieldInitValues) } }

Column {
    myLists.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = valueStateList[index],
            onValueChange = {
                valueStateList[index] = it
            }
        )

    }

    Button(
        onClick = {
            valueStateList.forEach {
                Log.d("Button", it)
            }
        }
    ) {
        Text("Click Me")
    }
}
```

Comment: looks great. I'll try first..

Comment: This would cause recomposition on every input word?